# Silverlight screen resolution

Tags: silverlight, screen, resolution

I want to figure out a way in my silverlight application to set the PageSize on my DataPager based on the maximized size of the window so that the scrollbars do not show when maximized.  Any ideas?

Comment: Just wondering, isn't there a event like Window.resize, or Repaint in silverlight?

Comment: Yes, but what I want to do has nothing to do with re-sizing.  This will set the pagesize on the data pager when the app loads so there will be no verticle scrollbar when the window is maximized.

Comment: But what about when the window isn't maximized, don't you want the page size to adjust according them too?  If that's the case, you'll want to handle the resize event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a post about checking in JavaScript if the Window is maximized.  If you're running in browser, you should be able to call something like this from Silverlight.

http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-127058.html

Comment: This is proabably as close as you can get.  The more I think of it, the less I think it is possible to get the resolution in a silverlight application.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I wound up doing it:

```
using System.Windows.Browser;

void View_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Int32 intRowHeight = 30;
    Int32 intTopOfFirstRow = 240;
    pgrData.PageSize = ((Int32.Parse(HtmlPage.Window.Eval("screen.height").ToString())) - intTopOfFirstRow) / intRowHeight;
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

This [page](http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Determine-screen-resolution-in-Silverlight-OOB.aspx) succinctly explains how to do it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.